# CustomTableViewCell Properties aren't being set (they are nil)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uiimage

I have a `customTableViewCell` that I am trying to set an image and some text on. The cell is created successfully, but the properties are `nil`. I'm not sure if there is something I'm missing in the `.xib`, but I just can't figure it out. The outlets are set in the `.h` of the `customViewCell` and connected in the `.xib`

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

  static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"socialMediaCell";    

  CustomSocialMediaTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

  CustomSocialMediaTableViewCell *tagCell = (CustomSocialMediaTableViewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"socialMediaCell"];

  if (cell == nil) {

      cell = [[CustomSocialMediaTableViewCell alloc] 
        initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

      tagCell = [[CustomSocialMediaTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
  }

  NSData* imageData = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"socialPosts"];

  UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

  cell.socialMediaTextView.text = @"TEXT";

  cell.socialMediaImageView.image = image;

  return cell;
}
```

Comment: make sure your outlets are @Property..

Comment: please correct the code format in question...

Comment: cellIdentifier = @"socialMediaCell" OR cellIdentifier = @"CustomSocialMediaTableViewCell" ?

Comment: Which identifier are you trying to use? Or have you put it in there to say you have tried both?

Comment: Also why have you created a .xib for the cells? Create a UITableviewCell class and then select the tableview cell in the storyboard and change the class of it to `CustomSocialMediaTableViewCell`. The drag and connect the labels and image to the class .h file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are referencing the same CustomTableViewCell twice and then you are allocating things to it:

```
static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"socialMediaCell";    

****Declared once here****
CustomSocialMediaTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

****Declared a second time here***
CustomSocialMediaTableViewCell *tagCell = (CustomSocialMediaTableViewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"socialMediaCell"];
```

Use the first declared `cell` and remove the second.

Then you are saying *if the cell is empty, style it* and you have done that twice. Do it once.

```
if (cell == nil) {

  cell = [[CustomSocialMediaTableViewCell alloc] 
    initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault];
}
```

Then you can add and assign the things you need.

I have a feeling that you may have tried to do this a more difficult way by modern methods by creating a .xib for it when you can just select the TableViewCell in your storyboard and set it's class. Then you can ctrl + drag from your UILabel and UIImage to your .h file.

If you do not wish to do this or have not structured it this way ensure that your referenced UILabel and UIImage are connected properly and that you have declared an **`IBOutlet`** for both - like so

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel * customText;
```

Comment: I just declared two separate variables to show different ways I have tried to do it without success. Yes I do have a separate .xib for my CustomCell, but either way it is still confusing to me why the cell gets created but the properties are nil @SASmith

Answer (score 0):

Edit inside `if (cell==nil)` with the below code

```
    if (cell == nil) { //Check cell is nil or not


   NSArray *nib;
   nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomSocialMediaTableViewCell"
                                                owner:self options:nil]; //if cell is nil add CustomSocialMediaTableViewCell Xib

   for (id oneObject in nib) if ([oneObject isKindOfClass:[CustomSocialMediaTableViewCell class]])
                cell = (CustomSocialMediaTableViewCell *)oneObject;

    }
```